# Remove host "localhost" in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, localhost, host

I'm having trouble understanding something, I've recently released a production machine, within the code of my application there is an automatic check of the configuration files, I need this to understand if something is missing, so I register the missing parameters in an exceptions page.

It so happens that, I have a method that fetches hosts like this:

```
 if(!request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-Host", out var host))
            host = request.Host.Value;
```

This as well as returning my 2 domains, also returns "localhost", I don't want this to happen, I removed the "*:80" bindings from IIS on the machine I deploy to, but that didn't fix the problem.

[image]

Can anyone help me understand how this works and what could be a possible solution?

Comment: have you restarted IIS (using `iisreset` command line) after removing the bindings ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but nothing has changed

Comment: Have you tried to checkout the header outside the server? (outside the network).

Comment: Yes, I do all tests outside the server

Comment: then I'm guessing it's on the IIS configurations, perhaps a port forwarding or url rewrite that was configured. try to check the configurations to see if `localhost` is used there.

Comment: That header can be set by anything in the processing pipeline (reverse proxy for example). So, while you review all sites and remove the unnecessary site bindings, you should also enable FRT to see where such headers come from.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.